# When is MS Access better that a web app backed by RDBMS?

Tags: ms-access, rdbms

I haven't used Access since high school, years ago.

What kind of problem does it solve well, or even better than a web app backed by a real RDBMS?

Is it still actively developed? Or is it pretty dead to MS already?

What are its biggest limitations?

**Update:**

What resource shall one use to learn how to develop a MS Access solution for small business?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First and foremost, Access IS a real RDBMS.  What it is isn't is a client server RDBMS.**

The *only* implications of this are that there is a throttle on the number of simultaneous connections and the security of the data needs careful thought.

Amongst other things, Access is also an IDE that uses VBA as its language.

This means that in Access you can write Front End apps that link to either a SQL Server back end, an Access back end, or a SharePoint back end.  So it is one very versatile cookie.

It's limitations are:

1. Security:  if you are using an Access Back End, take note that it doesn't have the built in security of a client server database.  In any app, security is a function of the cost and the requisite secrecy of the data.
2. Number of simultaneous connections.  if you are not careful, Access will struggle with more than 10 people trying to update data simultaneously.  You can extend that, but you need to know what you are doing to guarantee results. to put a number to it, lets say 50 simultaneous connections.
3. Like most databases, it is liable to corruption.

NOTE:  when referring to Access as a database, you should really be referring to the "database engine", JET or ACE, depending on the version and, for Access 2007+, dictated by the file format that you use.  In other words, if you are storing data in Access tables, you are using either JET or ACE.  However, if you are using LINKED TABLES, that are in, for example, SQL Server, then you are not, strictly speaking, using JET or ACE security for those tables.

1. Access SQL doesn't allow you to write stored procedures (you can write functions in VBA), in the sense that Access SQL only allows imperative statements as opposed to procedural statements (eg, control flow statements).  You can introduce some "procedural code" using VBA functions, but this is very different to using SQL statements.
2. You backup the file itself.  You can write code to do this at the click of a button.

Security is always a function of cost.  If you have data that is worth more than 100,000 US$ (either in loss of rights or legal liabilities if it is stolen and you have not shown due diligence in protecting it), then Access is probably not the answer.  100,000 is an arbitrary figure.  The precise figure will depend on whether the data is insurable and the consequences of it being lost or stolen.

Ie, if the value of the data is the driving concern, then definitely don't use Access as a Back End.  Whether you use it as a Front End, is a matter of budget. For US$5000 I have written apps that are still running 10 years later.  They now need to port the back end to SQL Server because the volume of sensitive data has grown.

Access, when used within the above constraints AND when used by a professional Access developer (rather than some disgruntled fool who thinks he should be using "cooler" technologies), will produce very sophisticated, sturdy and reliable applications at a 10th of the cost of other systems.  In such scenarios, Access is a total NO BRAINER.

Anything else will cost more, take longer and will only be as good as the person who writes the code and designs the UI.

I have an application (the first one I ever built in Access) that has run without problems for 10 years.  We have extended it massively.  I have moved into ASP.NET MVC, but Access is where I hail from and I have seen it work well.

So in summary:  the number of users is relevant and the value or liabilities implicit in the data are the other deciding factor.

If the number of simultaneous users is low and the value/implicit liabilities of the data is low, then the choice is definitely Access.

However, get yourself a good developer.

**EDITS/CLARIFICATIONS:**

The above answer, like all answers, was written in haste in the middle of a working day.  Some statements were a bit glib and generic and not written with a suitable degree of precision...  However, when the comments made by others are reasonable, the author of the answer should edit the post and clarify.

1/

Access is a holy trinity.  It is an IDE for writing forms and reports and functions to use in your queries.  It "includes" a database engine (JET/ACE).  It provides a Visual Interface onto the database engine that allows you to design queries, set up relationships between tables, etc.

It is usually referred in its many roles as just Access, but precision does help to learn Access and get the most out of it.

2/

Access can't use stored procedures in the sense that Access SQL can only use imperative statements rather than the procedural ones (eg, control flow statements).  There is a reason, I have always thought, for calling them stored PROCEDURES.

3/

Not every Access app costs exactly 100,000.  Nor is the budget of an Access app equal to the value of the data.  That is obvious.  The idea I was trying to convey was that if the data is worth more than a sum that can be reasonably insured, then don't use Access.  Is that figure 100,000?  According to Luke Chung and Clint Covington, ex program manager for Access, yes, but don't take their word for it.  It really just means "a lot of money".

I have written an app for Medical Charities that still runs 10 years later after an initial budget of 5000.  They have probably invested another 20,000 over the years.  That kind of app is the Access sweet spot.

Comment: Amazing--someone who's both rational and knowledgeable about Access. Though I think your doallar limits are a bit high...

Comment: Moneywise, I was just, roughly, quoting Clint Covington and the Luke Chung, the FMS guy.  So, as with so many things Access, just a matter of perspective... or is that ignorance?

Comment: +1! I'd question the $100,000 USD limit, as you can get into more robust technology for less (perhaps $10,000 USD would be a better number). However, in general I agree. If you use something like MS SQL as your back-end DB, and use MS Access for the GUI, those limitations are eliminated or at least mitigated.

Comment: "However, get yourself a good developer. If you are asking this question, that is not you.", wow, really? Do you really have to end your excellent answer with That?

Comment: Yes.  Most people don't appreciate that a good developer can develop a really, really good Access app.  A developer who doesn't understand Access will develop a poor app and give Access the bad name it doesn't deserve.

Comment: well, if Access is such a good platform, then developers like me gotta start somewhere right?

Comment: I would like to vote up this answer, but it's so confused on its use of the term "Access" when it means "Jet/ACE" that I just can't endorse it. For instance, data security is not a weakness of Access, as data security is provided by whatever back end you use with your Access front end. Data security *is* a weakness of a Jet/ACE data store, but only if the security requirements make it so. This is exactly the kind of distinction that is not clearly delineated in this anwer which is otherwise filled with good stuff.

Comment: Jet/ACE does NOT struggle with more than 10 simultaneous users, unless you're doing it wrong. 50, yes, it's a struggle (though not at all impossible). 10 should be trivial for anyone using good data retrieval practices. If you're not doing that, the deficiency is not in Jet/ACE.

Comment: "doesn't allow you to write stored procedures" -- depends on your definition of a stored procedure. A Jet/ACE parameterized UPDATE QueryDef would be implemented as a stored procedure in all server databases that I know of. What Jet/ACE lacks is procedural code and batch SQL statement executation. But it doesn't lack stored procedures -- it just doesn't use that terminology.

Comment: In regard to the $$$ amounts, last year I took over an Access app that had started life in 1996 and been used continuously since then. It was trivial, entirely driven by macros, and it was butt-ugly (see http://dfenton.com/DFA/images/OriginalCustomer.jpg if you don't believe me!). The client had wanted to update their database for years, but whenever they sought RFPs on the project, they got estimates in the $15-20K range and higher. I came in and they spent about $6K on the initial project, and a couple thousand since, and it has been transformed with all the functionality they wanted.

Comment: ...the point is, even in the $15-20K range, you can get a lot more with Access than you can with other development platforms (and some of those bidding in that range were planning to completely redevelop the app in Access!). Of course, I'm assuming a marginally competent Access developer...

Comment: "If you don't have a budget of over 100,000 US$, then Access is the answer (this implies that the data is not valued at more than 100,000 US$, otherwise the budget would be bigger)." The idea of the budget being (even nearly) equal to the value of the data stored is just plain nonsensical. I guess I could only wish it were true -- if it were, I'd be retired now, since I apparently should have charged around $100 million for one of my recent gigs (that, foolish me, I did for only a tad over $20K).

Comment: Did I say that every Access app has to cost 100,000?  No, of course I didn't.  Cool off, David.  I was really saying that if an app costs more than 100,000 don't do it in Access.  If the data is worth more than 100,000 in value or liabilities, don't do it in Access.  That is good advice.

Comment: Access can't use stored procedures in the sense that Access SQL is imperative rather than procedural.  Update queries are imperative.

Comment: @DWF:  your comments have resulted in edits to the answer.  Any others?  The answer now reads like an article.  The issue being that I didn't give it two days (more like an hour) to write.  Hopefully, it will do what it should in SO: document an answer to a question.

Comment: I don't think you can really claim ". . . very sophisticated, sturdy and reliable applications at a 10th of the cost of other systems" unless you've put blinders on to the proliferation of OSS RDMS engines without similar limitations, and RAD tools like Ruby on Rails/CakePHP over the last ten years which a good developer can cheaply create very sophisticated apps with cheaply.

Comment: Your definition of "stored procedure" does not match what is encoded into the DDL commands for Jet/ACE. No, there's no procedural code, but if you look at what is counted as a stored procedure in SQL Server, for instance, there's no need for any procedural code for it to be considered a stored procedure.

Comment: I don't know why you're going after me about the $100K figure. I didn't address it at all, but the comment immediately above your comment on that subject does. But I didn't write it, so I don't know why you refer to me by name when apparently reacting to someone else's comment.

Comment: "However, if you are using LINKED TABLES, that are in, for example, SQL Server, then you are not, strictly speaking, using JET or ACE for those tables." -- not true. If you're using linked tables, you're using ODBC, and that's Jet/ACE working through the ODBC driver to communicate with the database server. The only time you're not using Jet/ACE for data access in an Access app is if you're using an ADP.

Comment: Despite your edits, I still think you're conflating Access as front-end development tool and the database engine. The value of the data, the need for security, the need for 24/7 uptime, etc., all of those are back-end issues. They are criteria you use to choose your data store. The issue in this question, though, is surely about the development capabilities, and all of those back-end issues are orthogonal to that.

Comment: More than 1 but less than several.  But what's the point in me answering that exactly?  Small number and I must not understand access, larger number and I'm a bad developer, correct?

Comment: I would say your experience with a $5K initial investment and $20K additional enhancements over 10 years is very much in line with my experience. If the clients weren't getting good value out of the initial investment, they wouldn't keep coming back for more!

Comment: @mootinator: I think the point is that you have to have some experience with Access in order to appreciate what it offers in terms of both RAD and extensibility. I really don't see something like Ruby on Rails as comparable on any number of levels. For apps that need to be browser-based/web-delivered, sure, they're great, but that's clearly not the discussion here, which is about apps that could be but don't need to be browser-/web-based. And nobody's yet mentioned A2010 and its enormous capabilities when used in conjunction with Sharepoint Server 2010.

Comment: Right, so, we're comparing apples and oranges.  The question is "When is Access better than a web application."  And the answer is "When a web application isn't needed."  Which is somewhat of a truism.  *All* web applications are subject to certain limitations applications written using any language or framework are not.  It's sort of a pointless question in that sense.

Comment: "However, if you are using LINKED TABLES, that are in, for example, SQL Server, then you are not, strictly speaking, using JET or ACE for those tables." -- not true. If you're using linked tables, you're using ODBC, and that's Jet/ACE working through the ODBC driver to communicate with the database server. The only time you're not using Jet/ACE for data access in an Access app is if you're using an ADP.:  well spotted, I meant to say "... JET or ACE Security..."

Comment: DWF:  the conflation you mention is the traditional cause of much opposition to Access.  As a result, my answer attempts to address this conflation in many users mind.  You conflate me with my intended audience.

Comment: DWF:  your point about stored procedures is splitting hairs and misleading.  What is is encoded into DDL JET or ACE commands by Microsoft is one thing.  The statements a user can use are quite another.  You are conflating again.

Comment: DWF:  The issue is whether you can use procedural code in Access SQL.  The answer is NO.  A stored procedure can include procedural code, hence its name.  In Access, you can only write Access SQL.  Full stop.  You can't write stored procedure.  Full stop.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends really, I will give you a quick example that happened to me recently. At work they needed a small system to capture some records from a group of about 15 users and pass about 15% of those records to another team of about 5 or so to do additional tasks on those records. This was a one off project that was going to last about 4 months.

The official IT solution was of course a web app with a SQL server backend coming in at about £60,000. As they had no SQL server space available and the budget was very small I decided to go with an unbound access database using JET to store the data.

In this example access/JET was the right choice, now if this had been a long term system to support 500 users of course the web app would be the way to go. Its horses for courses at the end of the day and people should not let their prejudices effect their business decisions.

Comment: It’s a long story but the schema is setup so you can select multiple query types and info requests of each master record. i.e. the customer will ring up and query 4 things and want 3 different types of additional info packs sent out on the same call. I have one master table for each call then 2 other tables with a 1-many relationship setup. When the user hits save it goes away and makes all these records in one transaction.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  I've done a bit of that type of form too.   Of course I mostly use bound forms so I was wondering.

Comment: Many people fail to appreciate the beauty of a bound form with only one record loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Ah. Never. Point. Too many limitations in general. Backups are problematic, stability CAN be problematic. Especially if you compare access (file share daabase) against web ap you are in for a world of pain pretty much in every scenario.

Access is usable for small single place db stuff (loading data before moving it off to a SQL Server) or a front end for SQL Server (i.e. access not actually storing any data). The later is also pretty much the direction MS is taking access to - a front end technology.

Comment: interesting, I wonder how well it works with a SQL Server backend.  Have you tried?  It might be easier than HTML + CSS + JS

Comment: If you just link to the tables, it is as easy as using an access backend.

Comment: There is some truth in what you are saying but I have a couple companies running at least 5 user at the same time quite stably. I haven never found Access to be unstable in a small office environment.

Answer (score 1):

The Jet database engine used by Access is considered deprecated by Microsoft, though it is still supported.  The limits of an .mdb database and the newer .accdb type are described here.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100909161242/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/access/archive/2006/06/05/access-2007-limits.aspx?)

Even SQL Server Express would be better in almost every case.

Someone with very limited knowledge of RDBMS/programming can still throw a quick frontend together in Access (Ideally using an external database), that's really the main use for it.

Comment: JET continues to be enhanced. For 2010 there is a 64 bit edition, and this new version of JET (now called ACE) supports triggers and stored procedures.

Comment: ADO is being replaced with ado.net. In the case of DAO and Access? We now have disconnected off line mode support with SharePoint tables. For a good 10 years now Access has supported native oleDB connections to sql server (not using JET at all, but native conneciton). With access, you choose the front end and then can choose database back end (SharePoint, or JET (ACE), or SQL server). Note that Access 2010 has built in support for Azure. Access is not really the database engine. A2010 also can also create 100% web based applications.

Comment: Might consider having this document updated if that's the case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx#bkmk_MDAC_WDAC

Comment: Jet/ACE is not deprecated. Anyone who says that is likely reading MSDN documentation aimed at .NET and VS developers in the 2000-2005 time frame.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton ~ Just because you specialize in writing Access based software doesn't discount Microsoft saying it's being deprecated.

Comment: The deprecation is OUT OF DATE. Jet is in active development. Sure, it's been renamed ACE, but it's just a new version of Jet. Yes, it's getting significant revisions and many important new features (as well as having dropped some from Jet in the first ACE iteration in A2007). Jet is not deprecated any longer, and it never really was except for certain purposes. It really doesn't fit well into the .NET languages (though based on the volume of questions on this site, lots of .NET developers do seem to be using it, anyway), and that's the reason why it was deprecated.

Comment: ...the deprecation was also part of a campaign to replace Jet with SQL Server, including in Access itself. That campaign was abandoned by MS several years ago. MS's commitment to Jet/ACE is seen in the amount of resources they've been putting into it in A2007 and A2010.

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge is quite old now, but it always used to be very good for reports - very quick, powerful, and much easier than, e.g. Crystal Reports.

Comment: The report designer is now a "killer app".

Comment: The ease of report designing comes at a cost...and a pretty high one in my opinion. Comparing to the power of Crystal, there is a world of difference. You can hack Access into doing some sort of interesting things with reports IF you are willing to go through all sorts of contortions in VBA. Which can be sort of fun... Check out a few of my questions to get an idea what I am talking about.

Comment: From what I understand, Crystal Reports and SQL Server reporting services are catching up with where the Access report writer was in 1994. Until A2007, there hadn't been any significant updates to the Access report writer, but it's gotten lots of nice new features. I have no idea if the competition offers the same features, though. I've never needed to go beyond what Access offers. But my experience is limited to my own client base of small businesses, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hack something out quickly, it's probably a bit easier to do at least some kinds of applications with Access than a web front end with a SQL (or whatever) backend. It is still being developed (Access 2010 was release within the last month or two, if memory serves).

I haven't used the new version to say for sure, but the last time I did any looking, it seemed like new editions were mostly updating the look to go along with the latest version of office, cleaning up semi-obvious problems and bugs, but not a whole lot more than that. I wouldn't say it's dead, but I don't see much to indicate that it's really one of Microsoft's top priorities either.

Trying to pin down it's *biggest* limitations is hard. The "JET Red" storage engine it's based around doesn't scale well at all -- but it was never really intended to. Its basic design is intended to conflate the application with the data being stored, so it's *relatively* difficult to just treat it as raw data to be used for other purposes. I don't know if it's still the case, but at least at one time, the database format was also fairly fragile -- file corruption was semi-common, and in most cases about the only hope of recovery was a backup file (which meant, at best, losing everything that had happened since the last backup -- and some forms of corruption weren't immediately obvious, so corrupt backups sometimes happened as well).

It comes down to this: *if* one of the Wizards built into access can produce exactly what you want, or at least something *really* close, and you only ever need to support a few users with the result, it *might* be a reasonable choice in a few situations. If that doesn't (all) apply, there are almost certain to be better alternatives.

Comment: This post is filled with lots of untrue statements. Rather than call each of them out in turn, I'm just downvoting. -1

Comment: @David: Hmm...to paraphrase: "I can't point out a single thing you've said that's really wrong, but I **hate** the fact that you said it!" I hate to make what could be interpreted as an ad hominem attack, but somehow I get the feeling that you're *heavily* invested in Access...

Comment: Your second paragraph is wrong. Both A2007 and A2010 include significant upgrades at all levels, including in the database engine (e.g., table-level data macros in A2010, which gives the ACE the equivalent of triggers) and in new UI features (split forms, vastly enhanced design view in reports, to name just two), not to mention integration with Sharepoint, and in A2010, even Azure.

Comment: This statement about the design of Jet is complete nonsense: "Its basic design is intended to conflate the application with the data being stored." It makes no sense and bears no relationship to reality.

Comment: File corruption is common only for those who don't know how to use the Jet/ACE database engine properly. This is usually due to people not following best practices because they simply don't understand the relationship between the default database engine and the development environment, and have no understanding of the architecture underlying the applications they attempt to build. Ignorance leads to problems. This is not the fault of the tool, but of the user.

Comment: That's just addressing the specific comments, and ignoring the implied topics (like the implication that Jet/ACE can't handle more than a couple of users). This is an answer posted by someone who is either vastly ignorant of Access or is a very poor writer. Either way, it should be deleted, as it isn't in any way a helpful contribution to the discussion here.

Comment: @David: strange how you go on about how they're all wrong, but in only one case, even make the *slightest* attempt at "correcting" what you claim is wrong. In that one case, it appears to be primarily a question of wording: most of what you view as "major upgrades" look to me like the minimum that should have happened by Access 2000 to keep it *reasonably* competitive. An equivalent of triggers? Gosh, at this rate, Access 2020 will almost catch up with MySQL 1.0!

Comment: As for your claim that file corruption is always the fault of the user, sorry but it's just plain wrong. Back when Access 2000 was current, I sent MS a bug report showing three different problems that all led to corrupt files. It's *possible* they've all been fixed in Access 2010 (I haven't tested), but definitely as of Access 2003, they were all still there and in Access 2007 at least one still was (by that time, I'd seen the tests fail often enough that when the first failed, I didn't bother running the others).

Comment: Your comment about triggers betrays your complete lack of understanding of the Jet/ACE database engine. It is actually quite a feat of software engineering to implement it in a file-based database engine. If asked, I would have said that Jet/ACE would never have triggers, ever, but look what Microsoft did -- they implemented them anyway! That's a remarkable accomplishment for a non-server-based database engine.

Comment: I didn't say that file corruption is "always the fault of the user." There's not much point in continuing with someone who will try to falsify the factual history of the discussion.

Comment: @David: The difficulty involved in implementing it points only to the fact that the fundamental design of the database engine in question was horribly flawed from the beginning. Okay, not "always" just "common only...", which is still nonsense (the problems I reported were causing problems for a client about twice a week before I figured out what was going on). That's *far* too common to be dismissed.

Comment: The issues are the same for all file-based multi-user databases. Jet/ACE is no different when compared to the same technology.