# Recommended database to use with .NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-access

I'm getting into MVC and is wonderful, however, still need to decide what dabatase system to use. For many years my options have been:

1) MS SQL. For complex web applications. Example: A shopping cart or CMS.

2) MS Access. For smaller and simple ones. Example: a small product catalog, blog or news system.

I don't want to keep using Access, however, using SQL means using SQL Express if you don't want to pay more (my clients will not want) in SQL database hosting. But using SQL Express (when hosting supports it) get some some connection problems when many connections are opened (from your app and others hosted apps in the same pool).

I want to use LINQ, thats why now I'm forced to use MS SQL (express) in order to use LINQ2SQL.

Any suggestion on what database rather that MS Access or SQL Express can be used that doesn't require more hosting expenses? Otherwise I have to try Entities + MS Access. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered using a NoSQL solution? MongoDB|CouchDb|RavenDB...

Comment: Do any of the nosql options have a Linq provider?

Comment: Thanks all your guys for your comments, I think I should:
1) Address the MS SQL Express issue with my hosting, maybe is only my case.

2) Use L2E + Access (I read it do support Access and provide LINQ), but I still not confident of L2E, maybe new version is ok (heard of not optimized sql queries)

3) Use mySQL (need to find out if has LINQ provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most small to medium websites, I would definitely use SQL Express.  Its free and within its remit, works just as well as SQL Server full version.  We run innumerable websites with SQL Express.

Regarding Access, Access is no joke.  It just depends how you use it.  If I put @mattimus on a horse and told him to lasso a 450 kg cow (something I did on a daily basis as a kid), he too would be a joke.  It's horses for courses, isn't it?

To dispell the Access misconceptions, that are based on ignorance and false snobbery, see:
[Who Access really is (one very versatile cookie for a start)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094195/when-is-ms-access-better-that-a-web-app-backed-by-rdbms/4097145#4097145)

Just don't use Access for a website.  You don't need to.  SQL Express is all you need.

Comment: Thanks Awrigley, I have nothing against Access, but looks MS trend is to replace it with other versions of SQL for database applications. Anyway, using Access in MVC is not "easy", has not direct LINQ support ad that's the root of the problem for me. So I'm using SQL Express that works great locally, but is giving some connections problems at the hosting environment with the "full database pool" error. It happens very few times, but if happens even once, is not any good, so checking if there is another way of Free Database + LINQ

Comment: The idea that MS is pushing other databases to replace Jet/ACE is one that you'd get only if your perspective is defined by the .NET technologies. There, I can't see using Jet/ACE as a data store (though based on the questions I see on SO, a lot of people are doing it, anyway). But Jet/ACE is very suitable for desktop environments and is in full-fledged development as part of Access (and the Office suite). Microsoft has never recommended it as a web back end.

Comment: Based on all feedback I decided to insist on MS SQL Express, I opened a ticket to my hosting and hopefully the connection problem is specific to my case only. Thanks a lot to everybody for their time to reply.

Answer (score 4):

Access is completely unacceptable for any website that expects to handle more than one user at a time.

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/010514.htm

What are your requirements for the databse? Do you need it to be relational? How many simultaneous users are you expecting for your website?

I would either use MySQL or SQL Server Express.

Perhaps you can post the details of your SQL Server problem. We may be able to find a fix for it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware Access is not to use anymore, so I started using SQL Express. Problem is SQL express runs as a file database, not attached to SQL Server, then I have experienced some "full connection pool" problems in my hosting, that never happened with Access. Now, if I use complete SQL Server, hosting cost higher, clients don't want to pay more for a small product list website :)... I heard from mySql but never used it, so I still prefer to use MS which Im familiar with. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: The cited article is filled with wrong and misleading information. While I would agree that Jet/ACE as back end for a web-based application is not optimal, it can certainly support more than one user. The advice to open and close multiple connections is completely wrong with Jet/ACE -- your code should open a single connection and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much any database that you want with MVC. As other have suggested stay away from Access for web development.

SQL Server including the Express edition is a good candidate for small web sites. You can also look into MySQL and other cheap/free relational databases.

On an unrelated note, mi familia es de Merida Yucatan. :)

Comment: On an even more unrelated note, mi familia, a pesar del apellido, es de San Luis, Argentina...

Comment: in MVC no direct LINQ provider for Access, and SQL Express is giving me problems in hosting environment.. I guess my options are L2E + Access or MySQL (wondering if any LINQ for it).

On the unrelated note: De verdad? que coincidencia! Vivo en China, pero precisamente vamos a Merida la siguiente semana! Estas alla? nos podemos reunir.

Comment: Hey Awrigley! what a nice coincidence, your Spanish is pretty good. muchoo gusto! y gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many questions asked on SO, this one is like "how long is a piece of string?" You can't say really say what's appropriate except if you consider the environment.

For a read-only website, Jet/ACE can perform quite splendidly if you know what you're doing. Michael Kaplan's http://trigeminal.com is backed by a Jet database, but it's read-only. Back in its heyday, MichKa used to say he was getting 100K pageviews per day (or some number that was outrageously high, so far as I was concerned!).

But with a read/write site, you wouldn't be able to support nearly as many users.

That doesn't mean you could use Jet/ACE as the back end. If you have five users max, and it's an Intraweb app, you can be just fine with it.

I wouldn't want to use it myself, but it's not going to be a problem with user populations that are appropriate for the Jet/ACE database engine to begin with, and particularly if you manage your connections properly. Jet/ACE works better with a single shared connection than it does with constant opening and closing of connections (because of the overhead of creating and recreating the LDB file), so you have to code against it differently than you would with your standard server-based database.

Also, Michael Kaplan used to point out that via ADO/OLEDB, Jet was threadsafe, but via DAO, it was not. Use of ADO/OLEDB made it marginally acceptable as a back end for a web site, though I would tend not to choose it for anything other than a site that was very small or disposable, or where there were no options that were not outrageously expensive.

But the key point is that there is no blanket statement that can be made here -- whether it will work reliably depends entirely on the specifics of the environment in which you're using it.

Answer (score -1):

Access is a joke. You should go with MSSQL, MySQL, or Oracle. I like MSSQL personally. Access is not designed to handle large operations and is ridiculously slow.

Comment: He doesn't want "more expense" so that rules out Oracle.

Comment: @rboarman: There is a cheap/free version of Oracle. Oracle might be cheaper than SQL in some instances. I always assumed that Oracle was outrageous but I've seen instances in mid-to-large installations where it is cheaper than SQL Server.

Comment: There's more to consider than just the upfront purchase price. The ongoing price of Oracle including tools, support, backups, and even hiring people to help, is quite a bit higher than other options. Unless you need to support enormous websites, there no need to go that route. This is really a religious debate except that as a novice who doesn't want to spend a lot of money, Oracle should be ruled out. IMHO

Comment: rboarman is right. For big apps it is ok to pay for it (for that I do use MS SQL standard version), but tell your client to pay couple of hundred dollars more for database every year on a 5 pages website or blog... he will not be so happy :)

Comment: Access is not a joke. You do have to choose the proper environment for it, but the opening statement is just inflammatory and unhelpful for any purpose. -1

Comment: How you think it is viable for a production (web app since that is what he is talking about)?

Comment: Well, first off, I didn't come close to suggesting that Jet/ACE was a good idea for a production web app. Likewise, YOU didn't say that Jet/ACE was INAPPROPRIATE for a web app -- you only said "Access is a joke," which is not helpful for a number of reasons. It's not true, and Access is not even involved in the question (only the database engine is involved, i.e., Jet/ACE). Remove the first sentence and there's nothing wrong with your answer. Leave it in and it makes for a bad answer.